# STM32F4 USB device

Tags: usb, stm32

Вопрос относительно реализации USB в STM32F4
Я имею опыт создания проектов с использованием USB, но с использованием CubeMX. Но меня такой вариант не оч устраивает, так как создается проект тяжеленным, да и разработка для меня сводится к нажатию кнопки "делайчтобыработало", а в сути я так и не разобрался. Выяснил, что в самом keil есть средства для настройки usb, но как ими пользоваться так и не понял толком. Вопрос в следующем:

1. Что вообще читать, чтобы разобраться в принципах работы usb? Вопрос даже скорее, как правильно загуглить;
2. Для понимания организации usb в stm достаточно читать RF на чип или есть что-то доступнее (лезть в биты не варик, как я понимаю, хотя бы в общих чертах)
3. Как найти документацию на библиотеки keil для usb?

Возможно вопрос выглядит сумбурно, типа как найти то, не знаю что
Да и в терминах я плаваю
Заранее спасибо

---

Или подскажите хотя бы куда смотреть, чтобы разобраться в собственных средствах keil для настройки usb

Answer (score 0):

По работе интерфейса лучше начать с [USB in a NutShell](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml) Попутно скачать стандарт, полистать, офигеть от его размера

После понимания общих принципов работы уже можно смотреть, как они ложатся на реализацию контроллера в STM-ке. На мой взгляд, основным источником информации по ней будет библиотека и примеры ее использования, а мануал уже вторичен. Подобные библиотеки редко имеют какие-то детальные описания, максимум что обычно можно найти это собранный Doxygen-ом список функций

Полагаю, что если потратить достаточно усилий можно получить более компактный вариант реализации. Правда наиболее ценным итогом будет, не компактность, а полученный в ходе опыт.

Можно еще посмотреть [V-USB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-USB) - реализацию USB на AVR-ках, у которых вообще нет аппаратного USB.